# Using string literals in logger debug statement

Tags: java, string, performance, logging

We often use loggers in our code for debugging purpose. We write something like this

```
logger.debug("");
```

My question is, doesn't it create lots of objects since we use String literals in debug statements so much? Is there any alternative to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

String literals are allocated in a shared pool, so they will not waste space. Each equal string share one instance.

Literals are interned, as per [String.intern()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29).

Comment: @Juvanis The pool being shared means literals are only stored once no matter how many times they are used, so multiple instances of it don't matter, and are usually compiled away.